# Access window variable from Content Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sandbox, content-script

I have a Chrome Extension that is trying to find on every browsed URL (and every iframe of every browser URL) if a variable `window.my_variable_name` exists.

So I wrote this little piece of content script :

```
function detectVariable(){
    if(window.my_variable_name || typeof my_variable_name !== "undefined") return true;
    return false;
}
```

After trying for too long, it seems Content Scripts runs in some sandbox.

Is there a way to access the `window` element from a Chrome Content Script ?

Comment: BTW, you wouldn't have been trying for too long, if you had started at **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)**: _Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world [...]_

Comment: It is more complicated than this. I managed to `console.log` something that looked like a familiar `window` element (but was a dummy one).  So I assumed the documentation was outdated, which sometimes happens with Chrome Extensions. I finally managed to solve my issue by injecting code that reads the variables into the page instead of trying to read it from the content script (see below)

Comment: I wrote a simple module that helps you run JavaScript code on a webpage from Chrome extensions easily. Might help anyone who gets here: https://github.com/bluzi/chrome-extension-execute-on-website

Answer (score 78):

One thing that is important to know is that Content Scripts share the same DOM as the current page, but they don't share access to variables. The best way of dealing with this case is, from the content script, to inject a script tag into the current DOM that will read the variables in the page.

in manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources" : ["/js/my_file.js"],
```

in contentScript.js:

```
function injectScript(file, node) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', file);
    th.appendChild(s);
}
injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/my_file.js'), 'body');
```

in my_file.js:

```
// Read your variable from here and do stuff with it
console.log(window.my_variable);
```

Comment: The declared javascript in web_accessible_resources must be my_file, in order to be loaded into the page.

Comment: But what if i need content script to be both able to access extension capabilities AND window object?

Comment: How do I get the window.my_variable into the contentScript.js?

Comment: Why are you adding thru "web_accessible_resources" : ["/js/my_file.js"], and contentScript.js:

 too?

Comment: Injected script can store `window.my_variable` in DOM for example as a value of new `<input type="hidden" id="my_variable_val".../>` element

Comment: @IliaAndrienko I’m a couple of years late but this question still comes up on Google, so: The most elegant way I’m aware of to handle such communication is to dispatch custom events on the document.