# check and use jQuery / angular object in chrome extension from the website webpage

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to check if any website is using jQuery/Angular from looking `window.jQuery` or `window.angular` property on the website.
I have test website that uses angular and jQuery both. but in the chrome extension i don't have access to the *window.angular* but can access the window object in `content-script` that runs in the page context.
My content script don't have access to Javascript on my page due to security concern. 
I want to know if there is a way to access all window object in my extension's content script?

Comment: Possibly it duplicates with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, created a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/changelocale/mhbloikcjkimgboilnmmibdjfkociopo?hl=en-US) to tell if website is running on `AngularJs` or not. This can change the `locale` if the are using `pascalprecht.translate`.
[Link](https://github.com/lokeshjain2008/ChangeLocale) to the `code` you can change and learn from it