# How to call native page's function in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension, where I require to call function of native page to the extension js. How it can be possible?

I tried calling even on

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
```

but that even didn't work. Function of page is not available to chrome extension js.

Comment: Try the hack to access the web page by adding the injected script to web_accessible_resources in the manifest, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20513730/3959875)

Comment: tried that as well. not working

Comment: Use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to call a publicly available method in the embedded page via a content script https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript