# Chrome Extension Call Function from Injected Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've injected two .js files (Let' say for example a.js and b.js ) into a web page using content script, using technique mentioned here:

[Access window variable from Content Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script)

```
function injectScript(file, node) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', file);
    th.appendChild(s);
}
injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/my_file.js'), 'body');
```

Both script injections are successful. Now 'a.js' has a function called FuncA(){}. Now when I'm trying to  call FuncA() from b.js I'm getting following error.

```
b.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: FuncA is not defined
```

Comment: If you have verified that the scripts are injected correctly, it should work. The error is probably caused by some problem in 'a.js'. Would you mind posting its content?

Comment: You're right. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *proper* way of handling this is to rely on callbacks, not arbitrary timeouts.

```
function injectScript(file, node, callback) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', file);
    if (typeof callback == "function") {
      s.onload = function() { callback(); };
    }
    th.appendChild(s);
}

injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/a.js'), 'body', function() {
  injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/b.js'), 'body');
});
```

With an arbitrarily chosen 500ms delay you run the risk of either waiting too long, or not waiting enough in some extreme case. By relying on `onload` event for the script tag, you know exactly when it has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. The first script I was injecting was very big. So somehow the injection was not getting completed and I was calling the function. Hence I added some delay.

```
injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/a.js'), 'body');
setTimeout(function(){
    injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL('/js/b.js'), 'body');
}, 500);
```