# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined (google tag manager ,f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f))

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager in my chrome-extension, but on the maximum website, it will not load properly, give me the error `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined`  (f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f)).[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1tny.jpg)

[my google tag code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT7Ep.jpg)

Comment: Try following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart. You'll need to replace `GTM-XXXX` with you GTM container ID for starters.

Comment: @sh78 i replace gmt -id with XXX for posting question

Comment: Did you copy the *entire* code snippet from step 1, and follow *all* of the Google instructions? Also, what does "on the maximum website" mean?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the variable `f` in the line `f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f)` is undefined.  Here is the declaration of `f`, which is on line 11 of `gtm.js` in the screenshot you posted:

```js
var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
```

The variables `d` and `s` are being passed in as `document` and `"script"`, so `f` should be the first `<script>` tag on the webpage.  The only case I can think of that would make this fail is when the page has no `<script>` tags.  Normally this would not be the case because the GTM script is usually on the page, but since you're using a Chrome Extension, it may not be.

I would try this instead:

```js
var f=d.head.firstChild
```

Comment: this problem is solved,now I m stuck on dataLayer, i write this command in my code -->window.dataLayer.push({'event': 'mynewevent'}); but this not sent to google analytics, but when i run same command in browser console...this hit successfully in browser console ..

Comment: Is the push happening from inside the Chrome Extension?  Extensions don't have access to the `window`, so you might want to [inject a script onto the page to push the event for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script).