# React.js micro frontend subscribe to main app network requests

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, micro-frontend

I have a React.js app (chrome extension micro frontend) that is injected into another frontend app.

I have no permissions to alter the main app code.

Is it possible to subscribe and see the HTTP requests made by the main app?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can cloak (hook) `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` in [page context](/a/9517879).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can see what HTTP requests does the main app do:

```
const windowFetch = window.fetch

window.fetch = function (reqestUrl) {
  console.log('reqestUrl: ' + reqestUrl)
  console.log('arguments: ' + JSON.stringify(arguments)) // method, headers, body

  return windowFetch.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Update:

It works when the code is simply pasted into the page console, but unfortunately for the content script, *"The window object the content script sees is not the same window object that the page sees."*

Solution credit:

> https://gist.github.com/devjin0617/3e8d72d94c1b9e69690717a219644c7a

Inspired by:

> [Access window variable from Content Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script)

Aditional setup:

manifest.json (V2)

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["inject.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "content.js"
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
console.log(window);
```

inject.js

```
/**
 * injectScript - Inject internal script to available access to the `window`
 *
 * @param  {type} file_path Local path of the internal script.
 * @param  {type} tag The tag as string, where the script will be append (default: 'body').
 * @see    {@link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script}
 */
function injectScript(file_path, tag) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    node.appendChild(script);
}
injectScript(chrome.extension.getURL('content.js'), 'body');
```

**For Manifest V3:**

Changes in Manifest:

```
 "web_accessible_resources": [
   {
     "resources": ["content.js"],
     "matches": ["https://*.anywebsite.com/*"]
   }
 ]
```

Changes in Inject.js

```
injectScript(chrome.runtime.getURL('content.js'), 'body');
```